# How to change list of objects using RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to use StackOverFlow API. I want list of **tags** with **names, count and description**. The problem is that description is returned in different api function:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?page=1&pagesize=3&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow

gives me only two out of 3 desired fields:(try it by clicking on the link):

- 1)name
- 2)count

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/javascript%3Bjava%3Bc%23/wikis?site=stackoverflow 
takes tag names and gives me:

- 3)excerpt(description)

I built up a Retrofit interface:

```
 class Item {
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("count")
    public String count;
    @SerializedName("excerpt")
    public String excerpt;
}

class Items {
    @SerializedName("items")
    public Item[] items;
}

@GET("/2.2/tags")
Observable<Items> getItems(@Query("page") String page,
                          @Query("pagesize") String pagesize,
                          @Query("order") String order,
                          @Query("sort") String sort,
                          @Query("site") String site);


@GET("/2.2/tags/{tagnames}/wikis")
Observable<Items> getDescription(@Path("tagnames") String tagnames,
                                        @Query("site") String site);
```

So, first, we should execute getItems, then get all the names and execute getDescription func and finally  pupulate our Items with new fields.
So I want to collect all 3 (name, count and excerpt in one observable).

Here is my observer so far:

```
App.getServerAPI()
            .getItems("page", "pagesize", "order","sort", "site") //just example strings
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

How I should do that? Should I use  Observable in both functions?

UPDATE:
Following you advice I wrote a this so far:

```
public Observable<ServerAPI.Tags> call() {
                        return App.getServerAPI()
                                .getItems("page", "pagesize", "order", "sort", "site")
                                .map(new Func1<ServerAPI.Tags, ServerAPI.Tags>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public ServerAPI.Tags call(ServerAPI.Tags tags) {
                                        String tagsStr = "";
                                        for (ServerAPI.Tag tag: tags.items){
                                            tagsStr +=tag.name+";";
                                        }
                                        ServerAPI.Excerts excerts = App.getServerAPI().
                                                getExcerts(tagsStr, "site");
                                        for (ServerAPI.Excert excertItem : excerts.items){
                                            for (ServerAPI.Tag tagItem: tags.items){
                                                if (excertItem.tag_name.equals(tagItem.name)){
                                                    tagItem.excerpt = excertItem.excerpt;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        return tags;
                                    }
                                })
                                .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

                    }
```

Looks damn ugly!

Comment: you have to create an Observable that make a .zip with the 2 observables,
after is finished you have the 2 results, and with the 2 results you create the Item that have the name, count and excerpt

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
class Tag{
    public String name;
    public String count;
}

class TagList {
    public List<Tag> tags;
}

class Excert {
    public String excert;
}

class Item {
    public final String name;
    public final String count;
    public final String excert;

    public Item(String name, String count, String excert) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.excert = excert;
    }
}

Observable<TagList> getItems() {}

Observable<Excert> getExcert(String tagName) {}


public void testFlatMap() {
    getItems()
             //iterate over each Tag
            .flatMap(tagList -> Observable.from(tagList.tags))
             //call server for excert
            .flatMap(tag -> getExcert(tag.name),
                    new Func2<Tag, Excert, Item>() {
                        @Override
                        public Item call(Tag tag, Excert excert) {
                            //compose final data structure
                            return new Item(tag.name, tag.count, excert.excert);
                        }
                    })
            //item here
            .subscribe(item -> {

            });
}
```

**Update**

Here is example of calling Api for a list of tags.

```
class Tag {
    public String name;
    public String count;
}

class TagList {
    public List<Tag> tags;
}

class Excert {
    public String excert;
    public String tagName;
}

class ExcertResponse {
    public List<Excert> items;
}

class Item {
    public final String name;
    public final String count;
    public final String excert;

    public Item(String name, String count, String excert) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.excert = excert;
    }
}

Observable<TagList> getItems() {
    return Observable.empty();
}

Observable<ExcertResponse> getExcert(String tagName) {
    return Observable.empty();
}

private String constructTagsList(Map<String, Tag> stringTagMap) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String tagName : stringTagMap.keySet()) {
        if (builder.length() != 0) {
            builder.append(";");
        }
        builder.append(tagName);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public void testFlatMap() {
    getItems()
            //create map in order to easily find tag
            .map(tagList -> {
                Map<String, Tag> map = new HashMap<String, Tag>(tagList.tags.size());
                for (Tag tag : tagList.tags) {
                    map.put(tag.name, tag);
                }
                return map;
            })
            .flatMap(stringTagMap -> {
                        String tagsList = constructTagsList(stringTagMap);
                        return getExcert(tagsList);
                    },
                    new Func2<Map<String, Tag>, ExcertResponse, List<Item>>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<Item> call(Map<String, Tag> stringTagMap, ExcertResponse response) {
                            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(stringTagMap.size());
                            for (Excert excert : response.items) {
                                Tag tag = stringTagMap.get(excert.tagName);
                                Item item = new Item(tag.name, tag.count, excert.excert);
                                items.add(item);
                            }
                            return items;
                        }
                    })
            //List of items here
            .subscribe(item -> {

            });
}
```

Comment: I think this method is very slow and doesn't use all capabilities of Stackoverflow api: /2.2/tags/javascript;java;c#/wikis?site=stackoverflow -- we can put up to 20 tags together

Comment: @FixedGear I tried to show how to chain multiple api calls  using `rxJava`. If you don't want to iterate over each tag, than don't do it. Instead apply `map`/`flatMap` to create any other valid input param. Or do it directly before `getExcert` call.

Comment: can you describe the approach by extending your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could change `getDescription` method from:

```
Observable<Items> getDescription(@Path("tagnames") String tagnames,
                                        @Query("site") String site);
```

to

```
DescriptionResponse getDescription(@Path("tagnames") String tagnames,
                                        @Query("site") String site);
```

where `DescriptionResponse` represents response object:

```
public class DescriptionResponse {
    List<DescriptionItem> items;
}
```

Then get items and using `map` operator get descriptions and map them to your items:

```
api.getItems("", "", "", "", "").map(items -> {
    String tags = "";//iterate over items and grab all tags
    DescriptionResponse description = api.getDescription(tags, "");
    //iterate over items and descriptions in response and set appropriate description
    return items;
}).subscribe(items -> {
    //here is your items with descriptions
});
```